# Invalid property 'priority' of bean class [org.quartz.CronTrigger]: Bean property 'priority' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring

Error in SpringFramework 3.x  with  Quartz 2.x.x
deploy failed  WAR file in Jboss 5.2.0 environment

the error

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artifactBatchTrigger' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-quartz.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'priority' of bean class [org.quartz.CronTrigger]: Bean property 'priority' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
```

Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

the xml file config spring 
....

```
<bean name="artifactBatchTask"
    class="it.infocamere.middleware.mccplus.quartz.ArtifactBatchTask">
    <property name="batchService" ref="artifactBatchService" />
</bean>
```

......

I suppose a conflict libraries quart with spring.

thank you

nicola

Comment: Please add the ArtifactBatchTask code. So we can undertand what's happening

Comment: with or without properry 'priority' in Task class and/or in property bean is the same.

Comment: For me the problem is that Sring try to set (underground) 'priority'  properties of the org.quartz.CronTrigger.

Comment: The solution may be skip this setting priority by SPring